# How to install Ubuntu 14.04 on an external HDD?

Tags: 14.04, boot, windows, hard-drive

I use a Windows XP system with pentium 4 processor. Recently I've downloaded Ubuntu 14.04, copied it onto 4GB pendrive and now I wish to install it onto an external HDD (my passport 500GB) so that I can use Ubuntu while my family can use still use the Windows. When I tried to boot the OS from pendrive, cursor kept blinking and saying that: `boot from CD/DVD`.
I tried it many times, but it doesn't work. What should I do now?

Comment: Hi can you check whether you have enabled USB booting and also make sure you have installed GRUB on that external hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps will make it **easiest for you and the entire family:**

1. Hook up the external HDD you're going to install Ubuntu on.
2. Go to the BIOS and set the following boot priority:

   1. CD/DVD-ROM
   2. External HDD
   3. Internal HDD
3. Boot a live CD, and follow the [instructions from the Ubuntu.com site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Now your system is set up and:

1. If anyone of your family boots the computer, they'll boot into XP
2. if you hook up the HDD to the computer before booting, it'll boot Ubuntu

**Why not booting from USB?**  Apparently you've never done this before and USB disks are recognised as "hard disks" under Ubuntu.  More chance of failure.  (but feel free to use the [following correct instructions](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/#other) to put Ubuntu on a USB stick anyway and not listen to my advice)

Comment: nd as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)